# Can I insert a table when I'm using overpic?

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx, overpic

I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering{
\begin{overpic}[scale=0.3,grid,tics=5]{???}\label{???}
\tiny{
\put(80,55){\begin{table}
              \centering
              \begin{tabular}{|r|c|}
                \hline
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                \hline
              \end{tabular}
              %\caption{}\label{}
            \end{table}}
}
\end{overpic}
\caption[???]{??}}
\end{figure}
```

But when I want to compile it, LaTeX show me

```
1.247    \end{table}}
?
```

It is impossible to do that?

Comment: When you ask a question, you will get a much higher chance of someone giving you an answer if you provide a directly compilable document, beginning with `\documentclass` and finishing by `\end{document}`, that reproduces your problem or shows what you would like to do, and containing only relevant code (For example, here, no need for `[scale=0.3,grid,tics=5]`), called a MWE (Minimum Working Example). More informations here http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\put` command cannot accept floats as arguments, but you can insert pretty much anything else in it. Here it works if you remove the `\begin{table}`. You cannot include `\caption` if not a float, so if you do not want any, this will do. Otherwise, there surely is some way to add a caption somehow (`\put` can perfectly handle text), but in this case I would advise you ask another question (With a MWE).

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering\tiny
\begin{overpic}{example-image-a}

\put(80,55){\begin{tabular}{|r|c|}
                \hline
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                X & X \\
                \hline
              \end{tabular}}

\end{overpic}
\caption{??}
% {???}\label{???}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

A couple of other things:

- `\centering` and `\tiny` are not command (*e.g.* do not work like `\tiny{Some text}`) but switches. There are used directly this way : `\centering` and will affect all the current environment. In a figure or table float, just use `\centering` once at the beginning and nothing else. If you want to restrict their effect, use curly brackets like `{\tiny Some text.}`
- In a float, always place `\label` after `\caption`, otherwise it will not work.
- If you need figures for MWEs, use `example-image-a`, `example-image-b` *etc.* like in the example.

Comment: `\centering` and `\tiny` **are** commands however with unrestricted settings until delimited ;-)